# Printer in Haskell for Subst in Data.Comp.Variables

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, type-inference, unification

I have a function which returns a `Subst` defined in this library:
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/compdata-0.1/docs/Data-Comp-Variables.html#t:Subst

I am trying to print the return value. The printer should show a mapping from variables to terms.

When I try to print the result, I get:

```
  • No instance for (Show (Cxt NoHole CTypeF ()))
        arising from a use of ‘print’
  • In the expression: (print subst)
```

I think this means I must implement a printer. I know that when it's a user defined class, I can do 'deriving show'. Could someone point out how I should go about printing this?

Also, this is my CTypeF structure.

```
data CTypeF a 
    = CVarF Int 
    | CArrF a a
    | CIntF
    | CBoolF
    deriving (Eq, Data, Functor, Foldable, Traversable, Show)
```

It derives show, so I don't think the issue is here.

Comment: `Cxt` has no `Show` instance and therefore cannot be printed, no matter what parameters you give it.

Comment: Sorry, but I am new to haskell and I am not understanding your point. I already know the instance is missing and my question is how to implement it. So are you saying you can't define an instance?

Comment: @Lana It should still be possible to define a `Show` instance for `Ctx`. It would look something like `instance (Show (f (Ctx h f a)), Show a) => Show (Ctx h f a) where <newline> show (Term x) = show x <newline> show (Hole a) = show a`. Note that this is untested and so may not work the way you want, but a `Show` instance would look something along these lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Cxt`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/compdata-0.12/docs/Data-Comp-Term.html#t:Cxt) has a `Show` instance, but it requires its `f` parameter to have an instance of [`ShowF`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/compdata-0.12/docs/Data-Comp-Derive.html#t:ShowF).

```
(Functor f, ShowF f, Show a) => Show (Cxt h f a)
```

So you need to make `CTypeF` have an instance of `ShowF`. To do that, you can use [`makeShowF`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/compdata-0.12/docs/Data-Comp-Derive.html#v:makeShowF) with Template Haskell.

```
$(makeShowF ''CTypeF)
```